# Web Fonts from Portfolio

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am able to upload a .ttf file into the Portfolio. But when I try to reference the url in a @fontface the web font isn't rendered.

```
  /* Freight Sans Black Italic */
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Freight Sans Black Italic';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Freight Sans Black Italic'), url(http://image.email.slalom.com/lib/fe5f15707c62007a7410/m/1/FreigSanBlaIta.ttf) format('truetype');
  }
```

Is it possible to use the Portfolio for Web Font files???

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Freight Sans Black" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://image.email.slalom.com/lib/fe5f15707c62007a7410/m/1/FreigSanBlaIta.ttf

Answer (score 1):

For some reason uploading fonts to Marketing Cloud and then referencing them doesn't to work. This is due to a permission issue. You'll need to `base64Encode` your fonts:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Choose the 'expert' option and then next to the 'CSS' option select 'Base64Encode'. This will spit out a large css file with 1 font equal to around 100kb so try not to use too many, link the css to your landing page and reference as per normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm...weird that encoding has to do with permissions??? So once I use the webfont-generator tool...do I upload the converted font files to the Portfolio?

Comment: Not sure why but there seems to be permission issues when you try to access the fonts from portfolio. The above is a workaround. 

Once you encode the fonts into CSS you use it like you would any other CSS file when using Landing Pages or Cloud Pages. There's an example supplied when you download the converted fonts.

Comment: Hello victor. If this answer helped you then can you please mark as correct?
 Thanks!